# Spring boot database application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im working on the project with some video tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=851&v=lpcOSXWPXTk
Author in TopicService class is using inside the method findOne() comend and delete without creating a method for them. When Im doing same thing step-by-step I was unable to do it, any ideas why? I was extending CrudRepository and apparently this repo is giving you this access to findOne and delete commends.When Im trying to build project and going to http://localhost:8080/topics

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 08 17:16:37 GMT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

https://github.com/exovsky/wepappproblem << here I upload

Thank you for your help

Comment: Paste actual stacktrace and some code

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

First, this must be your project structure:

[image: project-structure]

Second add the @Repository annotation to the TopicRepository class, delete the methods you added, and replace

And third modify the code on the TopicService class as follows:

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    public List<Topic> getAllTopics()
    {
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topicRepository.findAll()
                .forEach(topics::add);
        return topics;
    }

    public Topic getTopic(String id)
    {
        return topicRepository.findById(id).get();
    }


    public void addTopic(Topic topic) {
        topicRepository.save(topic);
    }

    public void updateTopic(String id, Topic topic) {
        topicRepository.save(topic);
    }

    public void deleteTopic(String id) {
        topicRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

And a recomendation, you don't need to commit the target folder, you must ignore it.

Comment: I just edited the answer, by making your project work on my notebook

Answer (score 0):

Your `@SpringBootApplication` is in wrong location.
Put WebapproflApplication.class to the java/com or add custom `@ComponentScan`.

Refer here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class